# Items Unpinned from taskbar re-appear after reboot on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I just had to have my laptop re-imaged and am getting it all configured again.  There were some items pinned to my taskbar from the image and when I unpin them, they come back after a reboot.  I have seen lots of comments about clearing out %AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar and removing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband.  Also notes about c:\Users\Public\CompanyProfile (which does not exist for me).  None of these tricks have worked.  I even created a new users and am seeing the same problem on that account.  Another symptom I have is that when I default my browser to Firefox, it resets to IE after reboot.  I have checked and I cannot see any group policy that is driving this behavior.  I am out of ideas.

Installed programs to stick and items I place on my desktop do survive a reboot.  In looking around I tried a batch program to help and noticed that if I run these commands in DOS:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

It resets the taskbar and file associations.

Comment: Can you make any changes to your user profile that survive a reboot? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a good answer for a permanent fix.  However, I was able to mask the problem.  I ended up creating a task to run when I log in.  That task runs the script below and unpins to the items from the taskbar.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objShell, objFile, objFolder, objFolderItem, colVerbs, objShellApp, objVerb
Dim strFileNameAndPath

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

' ***********************************************
' Unpin Internet Explorer
' ***********************************************
strFileNameAndPath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%") & _
 "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\Taskbar\Internet Explorer.lnk"

 ' Verify the files exists.  If not, we are got and don't need to do Anything
If objFSO.FileExists(strFileNameAndPath) Then
    set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFileNameAndPath)
    Set objFolder = objShellApp.Namespace(objFile.ParentFolder & "\")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)
    Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
    For Each objVerb In colVerbs
        If LCase(Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "")) = "unpin from taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
    Next
End If

' ***********************************************
' Unpin Windows File Explorer
' ***********************************************
Set objFolder = objShellApp.Namespace("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu Places")

For each objFolderItem in objFolder.Items
    If InStr(1, objFolderItem.Name, "Explorer", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("taskbarunpin")
    End If
Next

Set objVerb = Nothing
Set colVerbs = Nothing
set objFile = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFolderItem = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objShellApp = Nothing
```

A special thanks to Syberdoor who helped me figure out the file explorer code ([Unpin File Explorer from the taskbar in Windows 10 via script or batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/1283962/unpin-file-explorer-from-the-taskbar-in-windows-10-via-script-or-batch-file))